# How to dynamically update the overlayNoRowsTemplate in AG Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

In AG Grid I am able to specify a custom template for the no rows overlay:

```
<AgGridReact 
    ...
    overlayNoRowsTemplate={'My funky message about no rows'}
/>
```

But I would like to dynamically change this, especially when an error occurs. For example:

- Unable to connect to server.
- No rows to show due to error xyz.

Is it possible to dynamically change the `overlayNoRowsTemplate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a state variable to the template:

```
const [message, setMessage] = useState('My funky message about no rows');

 <AgGridReact
    // ...
    overlayNoRowsTemplate={message}
  >
</AgGridReact>
```

Change it based on a button click:

```
const onBtShowLoading = useCallback(() => {
  setMessage('unable to connect to server')
}, [])
```

See this implemented in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/JkqW0IQP9wYph7kv).